# Is it really not possible to disable updates in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, automatic-update

```
              This is not a question about upgrading to windows 10!
```

I have read many times that in windows 10, you cannot disable automatic updates, which means windows 10 will download updates automatically whenever it is available.
Doesn't Microsoft know that this change would negatively affect people like me who have limited bandwidth and pay higher price for data? (This is almost true for people in developing countries).
Is there any response from MS about this?
Does MS really considered these people when they released their new OS in 150+ countries?

Is there any workaround for this?

[Pricey Data Is A Barrier To Internet Access In Developing Countries](http://techcrunch.com/2014/07/30/pricey-data-is-a-barrier-to-internet-access-in-developing-countries/)

Comment: My main question is the last one(are others off-topic here?)

Comment: You can disable specific device drivers and updates using a tool, and yes, on the home version you cannot defer updates like next months update or threshold 2.  We already have an existing question so I will NOT be posting an answer.  If marked as a metered connection windows update will behave slightly different, if you don't agree, don't upgrade

Comment: @Ramhound Do you have link to the afore mentioned question?

Comment: One forge related questions ... http://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-automatic-updates-windows-10?rq=1

Comment: News Flash: Microsoft does not care about its customers. I'm sure someone will figure out how to disable windows 10 updates in the near future.

Comment: Not to mention that many updates in Windows have had serious regression issues. The most common I think is the "Item not found" dialog when you rename a folder. It keeps coming back with new Windows updates, even after you fixed it in the registry.

Comment: Recent news is that in an upcoming release (probably the next big version after the Creators Update) they will allow the deferment of updates. HOWEVER, running out of date software and unreliable update processes have typically been an area Microsoft has received LOTS of criticism about in past years. They made the system the way it is because it is important that software be updated frequently. They are also working hard to make patch downloads as small as possible with delta file downloads being enabled in the Creator's Update dropping next month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to disable updates, its just little trickier.

One thing that came to my mind is to disable Windows Update service completely (open **Local Services**, search for **Windows Update** in list, open properties and choose **Disabled**).

However, this is answer that you are looking for: https://superuser.com/a/837949/193287

---

> Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
>   SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto
>   Update\AUOptions
>
> If you set AUOptions to “1”, Windows 10 will never check for updates.