# How do I permanently delete and cancel Windows 10 Updates?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, automatic-update

My laptop has *Windows 10* (as well as *Ubuntu* and Remix OS) on it. Every few weeks, I get some updates downloaded without my knowledge and installed automatically when I turn it off and back on the next time.

I don't like this at all. I know that the OS gets more secure, but I only use Windows for a couple of things, such as *Steam* games and *Blu Ray Disc* playing, so I have no risks. I don't even surf the internet from there.

Recently, when starting *Windows*, I am getting always the same update, that starts at 69% and goes up to something like 75%, gets stuck and then after a while cancels and removes changes applied to the OS.

I've got the feeling that the downloaded update is corrupt, and it's failing because of that.

How do I remove the update file and - most important - prevent any update from downloading, ever?

And if it's impossible, how do I delete the corrupt update to redownload it properly?

P.S. I know what you're gonna say: updates are recommended because etc., but please just provide an answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: It might be better to shift your question’s focus to the stuck update, because that’s the issue here. The rest is just wishful thinking. :D If you don’t like updates, don’t use Windows 10.

Comment: What the hell? So you just can't block updates?

Comment: Windows 10 does not give users choices about updates. they've gone to the mandatory model for non-enterprise clients. Generally speaking, many issues with windows update can be solved by renaming the c:\windows\Software Distribution\ folder, and then running windows update to rebuild it. that may help.

Comment: The consumer versions of Windows 10 no longer give the option. That is to try and reduce the number of compromised and broken Windows 10 devices out there. Enterprise versions have more options.

Comment: @JulianKnight, that is giving them way to much credit. They made this choice in their own interest, because it reduces the cost of their support operations if everyone is forced to use the exact same version. The real problem is that it allows them to force down shenanigans like the Win10 update notification software (which many define as malware), and privacy invading telemetry systems while customers have no recourse except to bend over and lube up.

Comment: You don't HAVE to use it! Switch to Mint Linux if you don't like it. It actually helps many other parts of the wider industry too. Though it is true that the telemetry is a little intrusive right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it really not possible to disable updates in windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/949221/is-it-really-not-possible-to-disable-updates-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are really determined to do this, you can simply edit your HOSTS file and redirect the Windows Update sites to 127.0.0.1 (the local machine). That way, Windows Update will never be able to connect.

---

However, that is a **REALLY BAD IDEA!** for the sake of all of us, please don't do it.

If you are only connecting to Steam, you most certainly ARE on the Internet and will become more and more vulnerable to malware. Being infected doesn't just impact you but is likely to make you part of a network of machines infecting others.

---

To fix your stuck update you can either restore to an earlier restore point and then re-apply the updates. Of, if that doesn't work, try the following:

From the command line:

```
net stop wuauserv
net stop bits
```

Then delete the files in `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution`

If you get a message saying the files are in use, reboot and immediately run the commands and delete again.

Restart your PC again and you should be able to resume updates normally.

UPDATE: In addition or even before, you should also run the following command.

```
sfc /scannow
```

This will try to fix any corrupt files which is something that seems to happen fairly regularly with W10.