# How to create a command that periodically stops and disables windows update

Tags: command-line, windows-update, updates

Yes, yes. I shouldn't do that.. Whatever. I've heard it a million times and chances are you wont convince me today. So:

Previous answers from years ago do not work because windows update service reenables itself everyday regardless of whether or not you disabled windows update service

I want to create a batch file (?) that will periodically (every 15 minutes maybe) stops and disables the windows update service. There is no point in doing it manually because windows re-enables it everyday or something like that.

What are the commands for stopping and disabling windows update service
How can I make it repeat every 15 minutes
How do I turn it into a file that I can put in my startup folder (ensure it runs in admin mode)

Comment: possible duplicate here : https://superuser.com/q/837946/738512

Comment: @SolarMike it is not a duplicate because that post is 2 years old. In that time, windows update has gotten way more insidious in methods of disregarding the user's settings.

Comment: If you had made the effort and specified which version of windows you are using that would have been a lot clearer...

Comment: it still works. I use the Windows Update Mini tool and this is fine to control updates

Comment: Oh, you just have not seen my answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10/1208866#1208866 I think one of my answers there or perhaps another is what you want but check out that specific answer of mine on that post and look at my other answers on that same post too. I think you will find one of those helpful but you tell me.

Answer (score 2):

As an additional way to help *postpone* updates, set network connections as metered:

`Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost]
"3G"=dword:00000002
"4G"=dword:00000002
"Default"=dword:00000002
"Ethernet"=dword:00000002
"WiFi"=dword:00000002
"Values"="1=non-metered, 2= metered"

Set them all to `00000000` to enable updates again.

**N.B.** [MS is, again, forcing Windows updates, e.g. from v. 1703 to v. 1709, despite settings to the contrary.](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3261969/microsoft-windows/microsoft-again-forced-upgrades-on-win10-machines-specifically-set-to-block-updates.html)

Comment: How much will it postpone?

Comment: Theoretically, "forever", but I beloieve MS has added *another* mechanism to force  Windows Update that may ignore this restrictions. See https://www.techrepublic.com/article/microsoft-forces-windows-10-update-on-pcs-that-were-set-up-to-block-it/ . Try Linux?