# How to tell Windows 10 when it is convenient to INSTALL updates?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Even though I leave my computer on virtually 24/7, it's like Windows 10 picks the worst possible times to put my system on heavy load to install updates, making it a pain while I'm trying to work and straight up ruining my gaming sessions.

I've been going through the Windows Update settings, and options related to when it can restart after an update are all over the place, but I can't find one to tell it when it is allowed to install them in the first place.

This option even exists? I've been Googling the stuff but the results are polluted with unrelated Windows Update troubleshooting and I couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: @eckes Yeah, my guess is that it is downloading updates as soon as they come out, which is great from a security perspective and all, but it's a pain in the ass. I mean, damn it, it could at least wait until the screensaver kicks in or something, why does it have to do that when I'm busy?

Comment: there seems to be a Windows taskplanner task which gets updated with a daily trigger to start the update service. However for some reason I cannot modify its properties to restrict it to run on idle system (and I really wonder why those tasks are so uncomfortable to be adjusted)

Comment: When you indicate you want to control when the update is installed do you mean, when the update is downloaded and becomes a pending update, or when the system restarts and the pending update is actually a installed.  As for the task you found, it’s not meant to be manually modified, your suppose to use the advanced Windows Update Settings to configure it.  Hopefully you will edit your question to clarify what you are attempting to control precisely

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \*disable\* automatic reboots in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10)

Comment: It is increasingly difficult to postpone Win10 updates,  but you can set network as "metered" to do so, until you revert it to unmetered. See https://superuser.com/questions/1302452/how-to-create-a-command-that-periodically-stops-and-disables-windows-update/1302469#1302469 . That said, I would not be surprised if MS closes that option with the next release.

Answer (score 2):

So, first off, most of your problem is probably not the system installing updates (that actually is not usually all that bad in terms of resource usage), especially since you have the system on 24/7, its most likely the system *donwloading* updates, which is insanely network intensive, and tends to hog the storage device too.

There are a couple of options to deal with this:

- The first is to just open the settings app, go to the updates page,
  select advanced options, and pause updates.  This only works for up
  to seven days, so it's worth just pausing them and then unpausing
  them when you're done for the day.  Not the easiest method, but it's
  reliable, and doesn't depend on the registry.
- The other option, which is more permanent but require modifying the
  registry or GPO, is to create a registry key of type DWORD at
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU\AUOptions`
  and set it to a value of 2.  This will cause WIndows to \notify you
  that there are new updates, but require you to manually download and
  install them.  Make sure if you take this route to still run the
  updates though.
- As an alternative to both of the above, recent versions of WIndows 10 (1803 and 1709) support bandwidth limiting downloads of updates.  You can get to these settings by selecting 'Advanced Options' in the Windows Update settings, then 'Delivery Optimization', and then 'Advanced Options' again.  They only let you limit it down to 5%, but in my own experience, that's usually sufficient most of the time.  If you've got other systems on your network running Windows 10, you may want to also limit upload bandwidth (Windows updates are torrent-style downloads now by default).

Comment: Downloading is sequential storage, it doesn't load the HD much. It's the installation that is the problem, the installation process. It throws the HD latency all the way up. Even looking for updates doesn't cause that, like it used to in Windows 7, but the installation does.

Comment: My comment was based on the assumption that the problem is caused by network load, not disk access (which is usually the case for most people). However, the first two options I listed will still help if the problem is actually because of the installation itself.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to check manually for updates if even there are any aviliable. When they're already downloaded you get the option to install them.

1. Open [All settings](https://www.windowscentral.com/whats-new-settings-app-windows-10-anniversary-update) (new settings app)
2. Update & security -> Check for updates
3. If any updates are available press Install now:
   [image]

Comment: This won't prevent Windows Update from looking for, downloading and installing updates when I don't want it to. I want to tell it that it can do all those things during the night just like it used to be possible on Windows 7.