# How to get the old windows 7 update options back in windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-update

I am on Windows Education Edition, which has all windows features unlocked.

I want to be able to select the good old "download updates but let me chose when to install them" option, like in the windows 7 days. How can I do this?

Comment: Those options were removed because people simply turned them on and never updated their machines resulting in a large number of unpatched machines on the internet with easily exploited holes. You can *delay* updates for a length of time in the latest version of Windows 10, or you can [disable](https://www.easeus.com/todo-backup-resource/how-to-stop-windows-10-from-automatically-update.html) or otherwise [block windows update](https://superuser.com/a/1366542/19943). Setting your internet connection to "metered" might also achieve what you want.

Comment: Depending on whether gpedit is available in your edition (no clue about Education) then you might be able to disable it that way: https://superuser.com/questions/837946/disabling-windows-updates-for-windows-10.  There is also a rabbit warren of duplicates to that question as well that might have a solution.

Comment: See my answer here.....https://superuser.com/a/983535/40928